# Scala Spark : Convert struct columns type to decimal type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have csv stored in s3 location which has data like this

```
column1 | column2 | 
--------+----------
| adsf  | 2000.0  |   
| fff   | 232.34  |
```

I have a AWS Glue Job in Scala which reads this file into a dataframe

```
var srcDF= glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = '',
                                        tableName = '',
                                        redshiftTmpDir = "",
                                        transformationContext = "").getDynamicFrame().toDF()
```

When I print the schema, it infers itself like this

```
srcDF.printSchema()

|-- column1 : string | 
|-- column2 : struct (double, string) |
```

And the dataframe looks like

```
column1 | column2    | 
--------+-------------
| adsf  | [2000.0,]  |   
| fff   | [232.34,]  |
```

When I try to save the dataframe to csv it complains that

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException CSV data source does not support struct<double:double,string:string> data type.
```

How do I convert dataframe so that only the columns of Struct type (if exist) to decimal type? Output like this

```
column1 | column2 | 
--------+----------
| adsf | 2000.0   |   
| fff  | 232.34   |
```

**Edit:**

Thanks for the response. I have tried using following code

```
df.select($"column2._1".alias("column2")).show()
```

But got the same error for both

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException No such struct field _1 in double, string;
```

**Edit 2**:

It seems the spark, the columns were flattened and renamed as "double,string"

So, this solution worked for me

```
df.select($"column2.double").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract fields from struct using `getItem`. Code can be something like that:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, getItem}

val df = Seq(
  ("adsf", (2000.0,"")),
  ("fff", (232.34,""))
).toDF("A", "B")
df.show()
df.select(col("A"), col("B").getItem("_1").as("B")).show()
```

it will print:

```
before select:
+----+----------+
|   A|         B|
+----+----------+
|adsf|[2000.0, ]|
| fff|[232.34, ]|
+----+----------+

after select:
+----+------+
|   A|     B|
+----+------+
|adsf|2000.0|
| fff|232.34|
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the dot notation `column2._1` to get the struct field by name:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("adsf", (2000.0,"")),
  ("fff", (232.34,""))
).toDF("column1", "column2")

df.show
+-------+----------+
|column1|   column2|
+-------+----------+
|   adsf|[2000.0, ]|
|    fff|[232.34, ]|
+-------+----------+

val df2 = df.select($"column1", $"column2._1".alias("column2"))

df2.show
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|   adsf| 2000.0|
|    fff| 232.34|
+-------+-------+

df2.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv("output")
```

and your csv file will be in the `output/` folder:

```
column1,column2
adsf,2000.0
fff,232.34
```